# Simpler way to thread dataset values to each other

Tags: dataset, associations

I have a relatively simple dataset that provides a list of values for a list of countries:

```
data = Dataset[{<|"GeoAreaName" -> Entity["Country", "Canada"], 
    "Value" -> 5.2|>, <|
    "GeoAreaName" -> Entity["Country", "Swaziland"], "Value" -> 398|>, 
     <|"GeoAreaName" -> Entity["Country", "SouthAfrica"], 
    "Value" -> 781|>, <|
    "GeoAreaName" -> Entity["Country", "Switzerland"], "Value" -> 7.8|>, 
     <|"GeoAreaName" -> Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], 
    "Value" -> 3.1|>}]
```

I am wanting to thread the values from the first key to the values of the second key so that I get:

```
{Entity["Country", "Canada"] -> 5.2, Entity["Country", "Swaziland"] -> 398, Entity["Country", "SouthAfrica"] -> 781, Entity["Country", "Switzerland"] -> 7.8, 
 Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"] -> 3.1}
```

I am able to do this with the following code:

```
Thread[Normal[data[[All, 1]]] -> Normal[data[[All, 2]]]]
```

While it works fine, I look at the code and think there must a simpler way that doesn't require me to first extract two lists and then recombine.

The actual code I am working on has quite a few more complexities than what I have listed here, so any simplification I can find will be greatly multiplied across all the work.

Curious if I am taking the long way around or if there is something more straight forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
Rule @@@ data
```

[image]

```
Normal[Rule @@@ data]
```

[image]

If you have more than two columns and you want to link two of them with `Rule` you can do

```
data[Rule @@@ # &, {"GeoAreaName", "Value"}] (* or *)
Rule @@@ data[All, {"GeoAreaName", "Value"}]
```

or `data[Rule @@@ # &, {1, 2}]` if `"GeoAreaName"` and  `"Value"` are first two columns.

Notes:

- `Rule @@@ data` and `data[Rule @@@ # &]` and `Rule @@@ Values @ data` give the same result.
- `Rule @@@ Normal @ data` and `Normal[Rule @@@ data]` give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Rule @@@ Values@Normal@data
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) implicitly on the [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html).

With `data` as in the OP.

```
data[All, Apply[Rule]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, for the entities as the keys.

```
data[Association, Apply[Rule]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

You can enter the entity keys in natural language using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, typing the country name, and then hitting the normal <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (i.e. not the one on the number pad).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is very helpful to see multiple solutions to the same problem.  While using `Rule@@@data` answers the question exactly as I asked it, I have flagged your code in my "cheat sheet" for data manipulation because I am sure to use it in the future!